# Fundamental theorem of calculus with functions of $x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

I have these two homework questions.Using fundamental theorem of calculus and basic (A-level) facts about intergration find $F'(x)$ when:
$$F(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) dt$$
I solved this by appling the chain rule and splitting the intergral (this might have a different name)
$$F(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) dt=F(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{c} f(t)dt+\int_c^{b(x)} f(t) dt
=-\int_{c}^{a(x)} f(t)dt+\int_c^{b(x)} f(t) dt$$
So $$F'(x)=f(b(x))b'(x)-f(a(x))a'(x)$$ by the chain rule.

Then question 2:
$$F(x)=\left({\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) dt}\right)^2$$

Am I correct in just saying $$F'(x)=\sqrt{f(b(x))b'(x)-f(a(x))a'(x)}$$
or is some more complex maths required?

So my questions are:

Is my answer for question one correct (and if not how would I go about fixing it)?

Is my answer for question 2 correct (and if not how would I go about fixing it)?

I know that homework questions are quite controversial but I have clearly pointed out this IS a homework question AND I have made an attempt at both of the questions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your first answer is correct, but the second answer is not. Try using the chain rule: $F$ is the composition of the function from question 1 with squaring.

Comment: so would it be $F'(x)=f(b(x^2))b'(x^2)-f(a(x^2))a'(x^2).2x$ or is that not what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer to question 1 is correct. For question 2 set

$$G(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) dt.$$

Then $F(x)=(G(x))^2$. Compute $F'(x)$ by the  chain and power rules.

Answer (score 2):

Your first answer is correct, but your second is not. You should be worried when your derivative has a square root, but the original function doesn't! Remember that the chain rule gives us, if $F(x) = g(x)^2$, $$F'(x) = 2g(x)g'(x)$$ You know what $g(x)$ is, and you know what $g'(x)$ is from the first part.